# C# Emgu, не знает классы Capture и HaarCascade

Tags: c#, emgucv

Пытаюсь сделать распознавание с помощью библиотеки Emgu. 
Добавил все opencv.dll в проект, с указанием скопировать в проект
Добавил ссылки на emgu. Судя по тому, что с использованием Emgu нет проблем, то дело в .dll opencv
Что я упускаю?

Visual studio 2017.
Версия Emgu: emgucv-windesktop 3.2.0.2682-сuda

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.Util;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.CV.CvEnum;
using System.Windows;

namespace Emgu.FaceDetection
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Capture cap;
        private HaarCascade haar;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используй [`CascadeClassifier`](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0/document/html/b940bc22-751b-d7bf-e9a4-8798e6f7ccb3.htm) вместо [`HaarCascade`](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.0.0.0/html/8071f5d0-e119-4ba7-308c-0002cb8fb90a.htm) и [`VideoCapture`](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.2.0/document/html/5d3e2a38-d2a8-494c-37e0-387d610a87ab.htm) вместо [`Capture`](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.0.0.0/html/18b6eba7-f18b-fa87-8bf2-2acff68988cb.htm).